# SQL query to get the unique ID's after a specific date

Tags: python, sql, datetime, join, apache-spark-sql

I have a table called test. and every week monday i will be running my automation script to get the new ID's added to the table.

For eg: If am running my script on Aug 16th Monday..I should get only the new IDs added to the test table for the last  7 days.

The result should not include the id's which is added before 7 days
So every week the new ID's which is added to the table for the last 7 days should be the result

as of now i am passing the query like

```
select id,revision from fx_results.test where scoring_timestamp_utc >= '2021-08-01' and  group by asset_id
```

Date shoud be dynamic in python script.

Answer (score 0):

If you're connecting to PostgreSQL then :
select id,revision from fx_results.test where scoring_timestamp_utc **between current_date-7 and current_date**  group by asset_id

You'll find similar date functions in other databases as well.